# "Practice amp" or "practise amp"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I'm rather confused as to whether you say *I have a **practise** amp* or *I have a **practice** amp* when referring to an amplifier that you use to practise your guitar playing.

I understand that the verb form is -se, but I also wonder whether "**practice** amp" is correct as it's a compound noun.

Any help and clarification would be gratefully received.

Comment: ***Practice vs practise:*** https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/news/view/editor/article/101/

Comment: AmE has [shifted pretty decisively to "practice" for the verb form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+practice+every%2CI+practise+every&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20practice%20every%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20practise%20every%3B%2Cc0) in recent decades, so it wouldn't be an issue for them anyway. If Brits were going to use a verb form it'd probably be *practising amp*, just as you might refer to a *bathing towel* (usually, a ***bath** towel*, but never a ***bathe** towel*). So it's the NOUN form you want.

Comment: A quick look at the relevant [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practise+amp%2Cpractice+amp&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpractice%20amp%3B%2Cc0) would seem to provide a pretty conclusive answer.

Answer (score 6):

You have a noun and a verb, and what you need is an adjective.

Both nouns and verbs can be used to modify nouns, but in different ways.

With verbs we can use a present participle ("practising amp") or past participle ("practised amp", though "practised guitarist" would be a more realistic example) or a *to*-infinitive ("amp to practise").

With nouns we just use the noun attributively ("practice amp").

It's the last of these that matches what you are looking for here.

Consider that when the verb and noun for an activity are more strongly different, such as *food* and *eat*. You would have a "food shop" but not an "eat shop" and so on, though you might well also have an "eating place" etc.

Comment: Yes, but interestingly when you press the ***re'cord** button* on your cassette deck (if you still have such antediluvian technology! :) everyone knows that the stress falls on the second syllable. So that must be a "verb" modifier - as opposed to stress on the first syllable (as a ***'record** player*, for example), where it's an "attributive noun" usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers probably influenced in no small part by the fact that they often had the word "record" written on or above the button. Likewise, "close" and "minimise/minimize" buttons on windowed UI and so on.

Comment: But what FF is saying is that [paraphrasing] 'With verbs we can use a present participle or past participle, or a to-infinitive postnominally' is not the whole story.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct. You would not say "**practise** amp", the reason being "practise" is a verb. One does not "practise an amp", do they?

This sentence might be useful:

> I am going to **practise** writing an essay by writing a **practice** essay.

<sup>Trivia: In US English, "practice" is used for both the verb and the noun, thus eliminating any confusion.</sup>

Comment: One doesn't practice an amp, but one does [verb] a [noun] for many nouns and verbs, so that argument doesn't hold as a general rule.

Comment: @JonHanna It was not meant to be a rule - I included it as a sort of thinking exercise to help the OP understand **why**, rather than just giving a plain old "yes".

Comment: Yes, I would hold that as a thinking exercise it is incorrect, though it happens to arrive at the correct result.

Comment: 'You would not say "practise amp", the reason being "practise" is a verb' is fallacious reasoning. You say 'stop button', 'record button' (as FF says),  'drag chain / net', 'drift net',  'pull chain', 'float glass', 'float chamber',  'tote bag', 'call taxi'. There are more closed V+N compounds (cutthroat, passport, scofflaw, breakfast, killjoy, turnkey, scarecrow, pickpocket, pushchair ...).

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Since it's a noun, it's correct here. It simply means that the amplifier is used for practice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an American guitar player.  "Practice Amp" is a noun, totally cool.  Someone was writing about "you don't practise an amp" or something?  Not a guitar player.  Downvotes a-comin'! (edit: darn, no rep...)

To my knowledge, `practice` or `practise` is an American/UK (resp) spelling thing.

If one should use `practise`, not `practice` when conjugating as a verb, as your question suggests, I think that is news the entire US population, we **ONLY** spell it `practice`.

Now, *go practice your amps!*